# SharePoint List Column Today's Date

Tags: sharepoint

All,

Does anyone know how to make a column in a SharePoint list that will always display today's date when rendered? I've seen tricks that require the list/item to be modified each day however, that's not what I'm looking for. I just want a column that whenever the list is viewed it displays the current date.

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to say that you use calculated columnns, but unfortunately according to [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA011609491033.aspx) the TODAY function is supported as a default value, but not supported in a calculated column.

So, outside of a default value, the only way to do this may be through a more involved effort.  I see two options:

- Use SharePoint Designer and the [Data Form Web Part](http://masteringsharepoint.com/blogs/beagle/archive/2008/08/13/DFWP1.aspx) to show a view into a list with an additional column that has today's date.
- The right way to do this is likely a computed field as it does not involve storing any additional information, but simply displays additional information.  I didn't find a good link that only discussed computed fields, but [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA102390461033.aspx) does go into a bit of depth.